# How to add labels to a d3 pie chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

Can someone please help me out in adding labels to d3 Pie chart.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/abhinavp18/tv64uypt/2/)

```
 // Globals
    var width = 500,
        height = 400,
        margin = 50,
        radius = Math.min(width - margin, height - margin) / 2,  
        // Pie layout will use the "val" property of each data object entry
        pieChart = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return d.val;}), 
        arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius),
        MAX_SECTORS = 15, // Less than 20 please
        colors = d3.scale.category20();
```

Comment: Can you add the code here?

Comment: There are loads of examples for this out there. What have you tried?

Comment: Take a look at one of Mike's examples here: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799

Comment: Hi, I  got the answer but stuck in one more problem.

I am creating a pie chart using D3.js from a json. but there happen a case sometime when i got 2-3 same names out of 10 names. But my code only fetches 8 names and show undefined for duplicate names. Can someone help me out in this.

    Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tv64uypt/3/